# How do I make this JOptionPane load this large arrayList vertically with a JScrollBar

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I make this JOptionPane List up to 100 items with a JScrollBar, I know it can be done. I'm asking for a little bit of guidance. 
Here's my code

```
public static ArrayList<String>  Matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    private void itemSearch(String name) { 
        try{  
            String string;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("items.txt"));
            while((string = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                String[] args = string.split("  "); 

        for(int i = 0; i <= 19461; i++) { 
            if(args[i].contains(name)) {  
                itemID = Integer.parseInt(args[i-1]);
                itemSearched = name;
                Matches.add("Name: "+name+", ID: "+itemID+"");
                System.out.println("Item name:"+args[i]+" Item ID:"+itemID+"");

                } 
            }
            if(Matches.size()<=1) {
                continue;
                } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Matches);

                }
            AMItemDatabaseLabel3.setText(""+itemID+"");
            } 
            } catch(Exception r) {
                 r.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Getting Users Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input).

If the number of "possibilities" is greater than 20, then a JList will be used to display the values.

So you need to use an Array (not an ArrayList) containing your items. So based on your current code you would need to copy the items from the ArrayList to the Array.

Comment: Well I still need help on the creation of a JScrollBar although I appreciate your comment very much. Could you help me?

Comment: `Well I still need help on the creation of a JScrollBar` - did you try the suggestion first?

Comment: So I change this public static ArrayList<String>  Matches = new ArrayList<String>(); to public static Array<String>  Matches = new Array<String>();

Comment: @CammyBoy, that is not how you create an array.  I said you need to copy the data from the ArrayList to an array. You can use the `toArray()` method of `ArrayList` to do this.